# Color-code Screwdriver Bits to size instead of type?

Tags: screwdriver, bits

is there some manufacture that Color-code Screwdriver Bits to **size** instead of **type** ?
my uncle is 87 years he can see its a torx but not if its T20 or T25, same whit phillips/pozi

the most used ones should be PH1,PH2,PZ1,PZ2, & T15,T20,T25, & and some hex..

and same color could be on PH1,T15,etc aslong its not similar size.

maybe easiest is getting someone whit colorcodeing removing it and buy a set of nailpolish or these pen.
[https://www.amazon.com/Paint-Painting-Ceramic-Acrylic-Markers/dp/B07485T22B/?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07485T22B)

Comment: That would be a good idea.  I am a quarter century younger and need reading glasses or need to try each size/type till I get the right one.

Comment: Stop using torx and help me revitalize the Phillips combination square drive industry. Which should be driven with either a #2 square drive or a (hardened) #2 PSD2-2, but can be removed by a third bit: the standard #2. Then there's only two bits to carry, half of which work on each other, half of the time, which is better than neither always never. When I need a **torx; gets pulled off the clip next to the other sizes and I see if it fits**, because it doesn't matter wtf it *says*; it's *gotta not slip* or you're SoL. If someone already f'd it up, you have to hammer on the next size up anyway

Comment: I believe the answer here is Krylon :)  However with Torx, unless you already know the size, it's difficult to determine it visually. You can't tell a T20 from a T25 or T10 from T8, they're too close together.  So you still must try sizes; larger first because a T20 driver will turn a T25 head (badly and damage the driver).

Answer (score 1):

IIRC (South of the relevant border) that is how Robertson bits (what you probably think of as [Square Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robertson_screw), because the US has a history of wiping the names of Canadian inventors from their inventions - see also [wire nut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twist-on_wire_connector)) are or were commonly coded (generally the handle of the screwdriver) in exactly that way.

- Orange = 00 (smallest)
- Yellow = 0
- Green = 1
- Red = 2
- Black = 3
- Brown = 4 (largest)

As for a paint marker, one made for the metalworking trades would be more suitable, probably - they are common. *e.g.*  Markal or Dykem (no affiliation but I own a Markal which has lasted years of limited use and not dried up.) Before your eyes go that bad, you can use paint to fill the etched markings and then wipe off the excess to improve readability/contrast.

Comment: Robertson and real square drives are slightly different, but you are right when you say robertsons are called squares.

Comment: Yanqui here, I call them Robertson.

Comment: @crip659 Have you got a citation or reference for that claim? I find nothing to support it.,

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/148066/how-to-deal-with-square-drive-vs-robertson-screws      It seems that Robertson's have a slight taper, where square drives do not.  Except in extreme use, I doubt most people would notice in use.  I imagine the difference could be seen if your had both side by side, but imagine most people are of type if the bit fits and turns the screw, it is good.

Comment: @Ecnerwal i don't live in Canada and don't use Robertson bits. how would a wire nut help me whit colors on screw-bits?  how many colors of Markal or Dykem is it ?